# Batch file: How to skip files path from .txt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to exclude copying the files from the path :
`AlreadyCopied.txt`.

`AlreadyCopied.txt` looks like this:

```
file 'E:\teste-batch-file\original\CG Animation Of Outerspace - Copy - Copy - Copy (1) - Copy.mp4' 
file 'E:\teste-batch-file\original\CG Animation Of Outerspace - Copy - Copy - Copy (2) - Copy.mp4' 
file 'E:\teste-batch-file\original\CG Animation Of Outerspace - Copy - Copy - Copy (3) - Copy.mp4' 
file 'E:\teste-batch-file\original\CG Animation Of Outerspace - Copy - Copy - Copy (4) - Copy.mp4'
```

I used `xcopy`

```
xcopy  "%Source%\*.mp4"  "%Target%" /EXCLUDE:AlreadyCopied.txt
```

I also tried with `RoboCopy`:

```
RoboCopy "%Source%\*.mp4" "%Target%" /XF "AlreadyCopied.txt" /Copy
```

Both with no luck.

Thank you for help.

Comment: Your file does not contain a per line list of filenames only. Each line contains an additional string, and also encloses all file paths within single quote characters! `xcopy.exe` requires such content, and `Robocopy.exe` does not use a filelist like that!

Answer (score 0):

```
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%g IN ('dir /b /s "FolderPath" ^| findstr /l /v /g:"The Text File.txt"') do (copy "%%g" "target folder")
```

For more on the solution, have a look at `dir` [/b](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir#:%7E:text=and%20all%20subdirectories.-,/b,-Displays%20a%20bare) [/s](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir#:%7E:text=%2D%20Last%20written-,/s,-Lists%20every%20occurrence) and `findstr` [/l](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr#:%7E:text=of%20a%20line.-,/l,-Processes%20search%20strings) [/v](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr#:%7E:text=that%20match%20exactly.-,/v,-Prints%20only%20lines) [/g](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/findstr#:%7E:text=literal%20search%20string.-,/g%3A%3Cfile%3E,-Gets%20search%20strings)

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?